# When using antd table, with checkbox selection, the checkbox is cleared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a main component and a child component where I use antd table.
The code does not throw any exception, and the selected ids are flowing correctly to the main component.

However the checkboxes are cleared after clicking on them, so I am not sure what am I missing here

Main component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Input} from 'antd';
import Form from '../../components/uielements/form';
import Button from '../../components/uielements/button';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import   ListPageTemplatesWithSelection  from './ListPageTemplatesWithSelection';


const FormItem = Form.Item;

class CreateModernSiteCollectionForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {Alias:'',DisplayName:'', Description:'', PageTemplateIds : []};
        this.handleChangeAlias = this.handleChangeAlias.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeDisplayName = this.handleChangeDisplayName.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeDescription = this.handleChangeDescription.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleRowSelect = this.handleRowSelect.bind(this);
    }

    handleRowSelect(ids) {
        this.setState({ PageTemplateIds: ids });
    }

    handleChangeAlias(event){
        this.setState({Alias: event.target.value});
    }

    handleChangeDisplayName(event){
        this.setState({DisplayName: event.target.value});
    }

    handleChangeDescription(event){
        this.setState({Description: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                let data = new FormData();
                //Append files to form data
                //data.append(

                const options = {
                  method: 'post',
                  body: JSON.stringify(
                    {
                        "Alias": this.state.Alias,
                        "DisplayName": this.state.DisplayName, 
                        "Description": this.state.Description
                    }),
                    headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }                    
                };

                adalApiFetch(fetch, "/SiteCollections", options)
                  .then(response =>{
                    if(response.status === 201){
                        Notification(
                            'success',
                            'Site collection created',
                            ''
                            );
                     }else{
                        throw "error";
                     }
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                    Notification(
                        'error',
                        'Site collection not created',
                        error
                        );
                    console.error(error);
                });
            }
        });      
    }

    render() {

          // rowSelection object indicates the need for row selection
          const handleRowSelect = {
            onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
                console.log(selectedRowKeys);
            }

        };
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        const formItemLayout = {
        labelCol: {
            xs: { span: 24 },
            sm: { span: 6 },
        },
        wrapperCol: {
            xs: { span: 24 },
            sm: { span: 14 },
        },
        };
        const tailFormItemLayout = {
        wrapperCol: {
            xs: {
            span: 24,
            offset: 0,
            },
            sm: {
            span: 14,
            offset: 6,
            },
        },
        };
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Alias" hasFeedback>
                {getFieldDecorator('Alias', {
                    rules: [
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your alias',
                        }
                    ]
                })(<Input name="alias" id="alias" onChange={this.handleChangeAlias} />)}
                </FormItem>
                <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Display Name" hasFeedback>
                {getFieldDecorator('displayname', {
                    rules: [
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your display name',
                        }
                    ]
                })(<Input name="displayname" id="displayname" onChange={this.handleChangeDisplayName} />)}
                </FormItem>
                <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Description" hasFeedback>
                {getFieldDecorator('description', {
                    rules: [
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: 'Please input your description',
                        }
                    ],
                })(<Input name="description" id="description"  onChange={this.handleChangeDescription} />)}
                </FormItem>

                <ListPageTemplatesWithSelection onRowSelect={this.handleRowSelect} />

                <FormItem {...tailFormItemLayout}>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                        Create modern site
                    </Button>
                </FormItem>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

const WrappedCreateModernSiteCollectionForm = Form.create()(CreateModernSiteCollectionForm);
export default WrappedCreateModernSiteCollectionForm;
```

Child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Table, Radio} from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';

class ListPageTemplatesWithSelection extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }

    fetchData = () => {
        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/PageTemplates", {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            if (!this.isCancelled) {
                const results= responseJson.map(row => ({
                    key: row.Id,
                    Name: row.Name
                  }))
              this.setState({ data: results });
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };


    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render(){
        const columns = [
                {
                    title: 'Id',
                    dataIndex: 'key',
                    key: 'key',
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                    key: 'Name',
                }
        ];

        const rowSelection = {
            selectedRowKeys: this.props.selectedRows,
            onChange: (selectedRowKeys) => {
              this.props.onRowSelect(selectedRowKeys);
            }
          };


        return (
            <Table rowSelection={rowSelection}  columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
}

export default ListPageTemplatesWithSelection;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because child component is expecting the `selectedRows` prop but the main component is not passing it to it.

```
const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys: this.props.selectedRows,
    //-----------------------------^^--------
    onChange: (selectedRowKeys) => {
        this.props.onRowSelect(selectedRowKeys);
    }
};
```

So when you select something, parent updates its state via `onRowSelect` prop. But it forgets to send the updated state back to the child via `selectedRows` prop. So the child doesn't know what row's have been selected and fallbacks to default unchecked behavior.

To fix it, just pass the `PageTemplateIds` state as `selectedRows` prop in your main component:

```
<ListPageTemplatesWithSelection 
    onRowSelect={this.handleRowSelect} 
    selectedRows={this.state.PageTemplateIds}
/>
```